# Python: to scan all IP devices connected in LAN

Tags: windows, python-2.7, networking, ip, lan

How to display all device IP address,Host Name, Manufacture Name,Physical address etc which are connected in LAN using python programming.

With help of arp - a I am able to get IP address mac and type(As shown below)[image]

but not able to get Manufacture Name and Host name I want to display the list as this[image]

Comment: For manufacturer name you need to lookup the [MAC address prefix in a list](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf). For hostname, you need to do a [DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Comment: I needed to find IP of device connected..This helped us a lot..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find Host Name using Following Method:

```
import socket
# Replace with your ip address
ip_address = "192.168.221.31"
print(socket.getfqdn(ip_address))
```

Use Following Code to find Manufacture name from mac address

```
import requests
 
for addr in ['B4:CD:27:81:F4:1C']:
        
    vendor = requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text
    print(addr, vendor)
```

Note: For above method internet connectivity is required